# Resize I420 frame

Tags: android, image-processing

I am new to Image processing I need help related to I420 image frame.I am working on a project which require some modification in live video. Incoming frame is YUV-I420 encoded frame. My requirement is to resize this incoming frame. Decoding I420 and converting into RGB & then resize is a costly process. So is there any way to resize this YUV-I420 frame directly.

Comment: You could manually do a resize operation on the "Y" bytes followed by a resize on the "UV" bytes that follow in the frame.  What type of resize do you want to do?  A quick and easy "nearest neighbor"?  Or a higher quality bicubic interpolation?

Comment: Thanks @selbie for your reply . I want to apply simple "nearest neighbor" can you explain little bit how can we do that.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you got a 640x480 YUV(I420) image.

There should be exactly 640x480 (307200) bytes of "Y" data followed by 320x240 (76800) bytes of "U" data followed by another "320x240" (76800) bytes of "V" data.  Think of each plane as 3 monochrome bitmaps.  That 460800 bytes total.

Let's say you got image bytes for an `X by Y` sized image.  Let's keep it simple and assume X and Y are even divisible by 4, as most video formats always are.  And let's assume the scale width and height are also both divisible by 4.

If you have an I420 byte byte array as follows:

```
byte [] image_bytes = <some array of image bytes>;
```

Then it follows that the planes are the following offsets within that array:

```
Y_offset = 0;
U_offset = WIDTH*HEIGHT;
V_offset = U_OFFSET + (WIDTH/2)*(HEIGHT/2);
```

Now a very simple nearest neighbor function for a monochrome plane:

```
void nearestNeighborScale(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, byte [] src, int src_offset, byte [] dst, int dst_offset)
{

    for (int y = 0; y < dstHeight; y++)
    {
        int dstRowOffset = y * dstWidth;
        int srcRowOffset = (y*srcHeight) / dstHeight;

        for (int x = 0; x < dstWidth; x++)
        {
            int srcX = (x*srcWidth) / dstWidth;
            dst[dstRowOffset + x + dst_offset] = src[srcRowOffset + srcX + src_offset];
        }
    }
}
```

So to scale your image to NEW_WIDTH and NEW_HEIGHT, you just do this:

```
int new_size = (NEW_WIDTH*NEW_HEIGHT * 3)/2;
byte [] scaled_image = new byte[new_size];
Y_offset = 0;
U_offset = WIDTH*HEIGHT;
V_offset = U_OFFSET + (WIDTH/2)*(HEIGHT/2);
Y_Dst_offset = 0;
U_Dst_offset = NEW_WIDTH*NEW_HEIGHT;
V_Dst_offset = U_OFFSET + (NEW_WIDTH/2)*(NEW_HEIGHT/2);
```

Then to convert your image, just invoke the nearest neighbor function 3 times:

```
nearestNeighborScale(WIDTH, HEIGHT, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, image_bytes, Y_offset, scaled_image, Y_Dst_offset);
nearestNeighborScale(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, NEW_WIDTH/2, NEW_HEIGHT/2, image_bytes, U_offset, scaled_image, U_Dst_offset);
nearestNeighborScale(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, NEW_WIDTH/2, NEW_HEIGHT/2, image_bytes, V_offset, scaled_image, V_Dst_offset);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @selbie you explain it nicely. I got it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Even thought the idea looks good, it doesn't work. It perfectly scrambles the buffer. I tried it with a smaller "image" of 20x8, which I "scaled" down to 10x4, just small numbers to be able to follow. Then I traced the indexes in the line, which copies from src to dst in nearestNeighborScale. This is the output, doesn't look correct (and it doesn't look correct with real images either):

```
03-11 18:10:41.558 16334 16617 D ..      : >> Enter
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 0, dst-idx 0
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 2, dst-idx 1
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 4, dst-idx 2
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 6, dst-idx 3
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 8, dst-idx 4
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 10, dst-idx 5
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 12, dst-idx 6
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 14, dst-idx 7
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 16, dst-idx 8
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 18, dst-idx 9
03-11 18:10:41.559 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 2, dst-idx 10
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 4, dst-idx 11
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 6, dst-idx 12
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 8, dst-idx 13
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 10, dst-idx 14
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 12, dst-idx 15
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 14, dst-idx 16
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 16, dst-idx 17
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 18, dst-idx 18
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 20, dst-idx 19
03-11 18:10:41.560 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 4, dst-idx 20
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 6, dst-idx 21
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 8, dst-idx 22
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 10, dst-idx 23
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 12, dst-idx 24
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 14, dst-idx 25
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 16, dst-idx 26
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 18, dst-idx 27
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 20, dst-idx 28
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 22, dst-idx 29
03-11 18:10:41.561 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 6, dst-idx 30
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 8, dst-idx 31
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 10, dst-idx 32
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 12, dst-idx 33
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 14, dst-idx 34
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 16, dst-idx 35
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 18, dst-idx 36
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 20, dst-idx 37
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 22, dst-idx 38
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D Scrambler: src-idx 24, dst-idx 39
03-11 18:10:41.562 16334 16617 D ..      : << Leave
```

Comment: The implementation of nearestNeighborScale is simply wrong. Checkout https://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/ instead. This works